# wpf project exclusively using pages, button_clicks, & NavigationService. Open StartupUri in full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a wpf app exclusively using pages, button_Clicks, and NavigationServices. I wish to open the MainPage with the equivalent of WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None".  But these properties do not seem to exist for a page? I have searched extensively and only get the Windows solution.

Comment: But a page *exists* in a window, so how would those properties work? (if they existed)

Answer (score 0):

Your page should be within a Navigation Window or in a frame that is in a Window.

You can set the WindowState and WindowStyle in a Navigation Window similar to how you do so for a Window.

```
<NavigationWindow ...
   ...
   WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
```